# Cannot Read Property within code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep on getting this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property "6" from undefined.
```

I'm thought my code was right but I can't find what's wrong.

The advocateEmail function should be getting the row data from the findSend function. However, when I run the find send function it doesn't work.

```
 function findSend() {
      var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var tsRows = parseInt(tsSheet.getLastRow());
  var tsRange = tsSheet.getRange("A2:F"+tsRows);
  var tsData = tsRange.getValues();

  for (i = 1; i < (tsRows); i++) { 
    var row = tsData[i];
    var sheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[6]), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    Logger.log("ROW: "+row);
    //Logger.log("LOG:"+String(tsData[i].getValue()));
    if( sheetDate == todaysDate) {
     advocateEmail(row);
     Logger.log(row);
    }
  }
}

  // Send email to advocate



function advocateEmail(row) {

  var recipient= row[6]; // Who the email is sent to
  var subject= sendTheseName[1] + sendTheseLName[2] + " - Starting today"; // Subject of the message
  var message= sendTheseBackup[4] + " - Backup Code"; // Contents of the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
};
```

If anyone could help find out what's happening that would be great!

Example data:

```
Timestamp   First Name  Last Name   Email   Backup code Start Date  Advocate Email  Sender
29/09/2017  Blah    Blah    Blah@blah.com   iewfiw  02/10/2017  Blah@blah.com   Anon
```

Comment: What is `tsData`? is it an array of values or an array of arrays?

Comment: It's all the values between A2 to F+ Last Row

Comment: but what actually is the data? could you possibly include a snippet of what it is?

Comment: Updated main post :)

Comment: so `tsData` is an object of data?

Comment: Basically yeah,

Comment: in which case, im not sure why it says undefined but as its an object not array, there isnt a 6th index, you would need something like `var recipient = row.email;` depending on what the field is actually called

Comment: try calling `advocateEmail(row[6]);` and in the function leave `var recipient= row[6];` as I see the rest of the row does not reoccur in that function. Javascript is weird with arrays. I believe that if you were to do `row[6] = test` as a result you would have `tsData[i][6] == test` as well. Operator `=` works more like a pointer with arrays rather than the value itself

Comment: Nope didn't work. It's weird because it should work as the data is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
var tsRange = tsSheet.getRange("A2:F"+tsRows);
```

results in a range with tsRows-1 rows, since you excluded row 1. So, tsData has rows indexed by 0,1,...tsRows-2. When your loop

```
for (i = 1; i < (tsRows); i++) { 
  var row = tsData[i];
```

runs with i value of tsRows-1, the variable row is undefined due to i being out of index range. Hence the error.

I think the underlying problem is that you did not account for JavaScript indexes beginning with 0. The same issue is present in `row[6]`. Since the array `row` has 6 elements, coming from columns A,B,C,D,E,F, they are numbered 0,1,2,3,4,5. There is no `row[6]`.

I would also suggest to loop over double arrays according to their actual size, as in

```
for (i = 0; i < tsData.length; i++) {
  ... do something with tsData[i] 
}
```

Comment: Turns out it was because I didn't call all the data. Edited your post with how I fixed a second part as well